# Strange behaviour with composite-id and version in hibernate 3.6

Tags: java, hibernate

I encounter strange behaviour on Hibernate's `merge()` if I use an entity with a composite-id and a version number.

This is my hibernate mapping file:

```
<class name="ArticleTurnover" table="T_ARTICLETURNOVER">
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="mainArticleId" type="java.lang.Integer" column="ARTICLETURNOVER_ID"/>
        <key-property name="locationId" type="java.lang.Integer" column="ARTICLETURNOVER_LOCATIONID"/>
    </composite-id>

    <version name="version" column="ARTICLETURNOVER_VERSION" />
    ... some properties
</class>
```

And this is the code (it fails...):

```
ArticleTurnover at = new ArticleTurnover();
at.setMainArticleId(1);
at.setLocationId(1);
ArticleTurnover savedAt = em.merge(at);
assertNotNull(savedAt.getMainArticleId());
assertNotNull(savedAt.getLocationId());
```

After calling `merge` the fields mainArticleId and locationId are both `null`. The code above is just a test, but if I would commit a transaction, hibernate would insert null into the composite-id fields, and fail!

If I change `em.merge(at)` to `em.persist(at)` everything works. And if I manually set `at.setVersion(0)` (!!) it also works.

I ended up in adding a component type `ArticleTurnoverId` for my composite-id like mentioned here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e4819.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong, or point out why this happens?

Comment: What happens when you use merge?

Comment: Sorry it was not very clear, I clarified my problem!

Comment: Is the code you are testing for a new entity or existing one? For new entities, use persist and use merge for existing ones.

Comment: I know that, but merge should work for new entities too! My question is what is merge doing to my fields??